# Complex MS Access Form controls not changing background color

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an unbound form with 300+ controls on it that pulls data from line items on an order (via a reccordset) and does calculations to count different products. It's possible to have multiple products with a width of 1, 2, 3, etc counted on this form, it is then programmed in VBA to set the background color of changed values to vbGreen when setting the textbox values so that the user can easily see what has changed.

My boxes are being filled with values however the green background is only showing when you click in the box

```
If Double20 <> 0 Then
  Me.Double20.Value = Double20
  Me.Double20.BackColor = VbGreen
End If
```

Double20 is the variable holding the count (and yes I did try changing the variable name to check for conflicts)

Any Ideas?

Edit: I also tried referring to it explicitly

```
Forms![DWO Creator Form]![Double20].BackColor = vbRed
```

and that changes it to red (but only after clicking in it)

Comment: Please use some punctuation in your first paragraph, it's really hard to read. --- You shouldn't have a variable with the same name as a control on your form. That is a sure way to confusion.

Comment: I changed the name of the variable though and it didn't fix the problem

Comment: Try adding a Form.Refresh in that If/Then block.  Sometimes the form doesn't refresh without it.

Comment: Or maybe `Me.Repaint` after changing `BackColor`

Comment: Jonny and Hans they sound good but didn't fix the problem unfortunately

Comment: Did you try putting in a break point and stepping through the code to make sure it's actually firing?

Comment: @Johny Bones putting a breakpoint on the next line and checking the values shows the backcolor of the field with the same # as vbGreen putting the breakpoint on that line shows different #s

Comment: I don't understand what's going on, but I suspect we'll need more information.  What is the context of your code sample?  Is it part of an event procedure such as Form Current, a command button click event, etc.?  Is the form's display mode Single Form, Continuous Form, or Datasheet?  What are the specific features of `Me.Double20` which cause you to call it "complex" --- in other words, how it is more complex than any other text box?

Comment: It's applied in Form Load in a single form.  Background: There is a Orders form with a line items subform, when someone clicks on a work order that has DWO in it on the subform, it opens this second form and will run a large amount of logic to count how many Left Hand, Right Hand, Double, and Bifold Doors of each size are needed.

Comment: I'm stuck.  Can you share a copy of your database?

Comment: I unfortunately can't give you my entire database but here's a copy of the form the 2/0 Double door box should be red  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rxbi5kly03py8o1/DWO.accdb?dl=0

Comment: Looks like Andre already got there.  His explanation sounds spot on to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your textboxes have a **transparent** background.

You either need to set it to "Normal" in design view, or add

```
Me.Double20.BackStyle = 1
```

when setting the `.BackColor`.

In retrospect, this should have been obvious - controls showing their backcolor only when they have the focus is exactly the behavior of a transparent background...

Comment: Thank You that did it I've never had that problem before with a form and Don't think I modified the initial text box that I filled out the form with